# Unable to save a custom product attribute created manually

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3.5

I've created a custom product attribute: `my_custom_attribute` from the backoffice and assigned it to the right attribute set.

Now I am trying to set some values for my attribute programatically. This is my code:

```
//Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
$myProduct = $this->product->getById(123);
$myProduct->setData('my_custom_attribute', 'test');
$this->product->save($myProduct);
```

When I run that code, it is executed with success, no errors, no exceptions. But my product attribute is empty. IF I add some random string manually and save it from the backoffice and rerun my script, I got the right value: `test`.

Did someone face this issue ? I know it is weird.. Please share your thoughts! Thank you

Comment: After your script have try to run caching and indexing commands and then check.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to save custom attribute value

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setCustomAttribute($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: still the same results :(

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to save a product.
List ranging from the "heaviest" to the lightest in terms of resources:

- Repository
- ResourceModel
- ResourceConnection, it is more difficult varies according to the type of product

Via repository

```
public $repo;

__construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $repo) {
$this->repo = $repo;
}

/** \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product **/
$this->repo->save($product)


Via Resource Model:

__construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $productResource) {
$this->productResource = $productResource;
}


/** \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product **/
$this->productResource->save($product)
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work. Also if it doesn't, you should see the catch message at least.

```
try {
    $myProduct = $this->productRepository->getById(123, true, 0);
    $myProduct->setData('my_custom_attribute', 'test');
    $this->productRepository->save($myProduct);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'An error occured'
}
```